# Which elements can Googlebot read on this page?

Tags: angular, seo, googlebot

Here is a webpage and I need to know which elements Googlebot can read and which elements it cannot read.

https://www.cashrewards.com.au/asos

I inspected the page and I saw a whole bunch of empty paragraph tags

.

I am an SEO beginner. Can anybody please give me some tips.

Thank you very much.

Comment: This is why server side rendered solutions such as angular universal exist https://angular.io/guide/universal

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use Server Side Rendering with Angular Universal to solve this.

There is a way to update the meta data on route change, but it won't affect bot scraping, thus it won't have any SEO affect.  SSR is the only solution.

https://angular.io/guide/universal

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I want to know which elements on that page can be read, and which can't be read.

Comment: You'll need to simulate what a spider sees for the given url. There are a lot of tools that can do this, https://theseotools.net/spider-simulator is one for example. That should give you an idea of what's visible on your Angular app's route.

Comment: @Brandon no offense, but that is irrelevant that's now how the browser bots work.  If the app is served in the browser instead of by the server, the bots don't get notified that the route has changed, so updating meta means nothing for the bots.  Hope that helps.

Comment: @anothercoder No, I understand that, but if the URL is accessed directly, Node is going to render that initial route and whatever meta tags should be there to be indexed. You're correct in that once the initial route is rendered, Angular takes over routing and that's completely client-side.

Answer (score 0):

There is another option if you do not want to go with Server Side Rendering is to use Title and Meta from '@angular/platform-browser'. Meta elements are typically used to specify the page description, keywords, author, last modified, and other metadata which plays an important role in SEO.

```
this.titleService.setTitle('Angular and SEO problems');
this.meta.addTag({ name: 'description', content: 'Angular and SEO problems' });
this.meta.addTag({ name: 'author', content: '' });
this.meta.addTag({ name: 'keywords', content: '' });
```

Comment: You can add meta all you want, but as you navigate manually through the app, the meta will update on the fly, however, it's not detectable by SEO bots.